# how to change navigation animation to left to right in swift 4?

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

I have a navigation bar in my application that I change the navigation to present modally  But I want when user goes to the destination view controller the navigation animation from left to right

here is my codes in the first view controller

```
    @IBAction func showProfilePage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showprofile", sender: self)


}
```

I read apple site for this and use this function too

```
private func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                                   willShow viewController: ProfileViewController,
                                   animated: Bool) {




}
```

But it doesn't work so what should I do to change navigation animation from left to right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PatientCheckout", bundle:nil)
let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientCheckoutViewController") as UIViewController

let transition = CATransition.init()
transition.duration = 0.45
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush //Transition you want like Push, Reveal
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft // Direction like Left to Right, Right to Left
transition.delegate = self
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: thanks for answering! Please put in more of an explanation to this answer. Code-only answers tend to get flagged for low quality.

Comment: thanks this was useful and every things looks good But this page won't coming inFront of the current page

Comment: replace self.navigationController?.view!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition) with view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)